# variable columns amount Anorm result set parser

Tags: scala, anorm

I'm experimenting with scala, here is my stack:

- Windows 10
- JDK 1.8
- Scala 2.11.8
- PlayFramework 2.5
- Anorm 2.4.0
- MySql
                5.5

I want to create a result set parser with Anorm that will be able to parse any amount of columns that I select from a given table. Here is my code:

```
case class Campaign(id: Int, campaign_mode_id: Int, name: String)

class Application @Inject()(db: Database) extends Controller {

  val campaign = {
    get[Int]("campaign.id") ~
    get[Int]("campaign.campaign_mode_id") ~
    get[String]("campaign.name") map {
      case id ~ campaign_mode_id ~ name  => Campaign(id, campaign_mode_id, name)
    }
  }

  def index = Action {
    val data : List[Campaign] = db.withConnection { implicit connection =>
      SQL("SELECT id, campaign_mode_id, name FROM campaign").as(campaign.*)
    }

    Ok(views.html.index(data))
  }
}
```

I want to be able to run following Sqls and still use the same `case class Campaign`:

```
SELECT id, name FROM campaign
SELECT name FROM campaign
```

How can I achieve this functionality ?

**UPDATE:**

I updated my code changing type of some fields to Option:

```
case class Campaign(id: Int, campaign_mode_id: Option[Int], name: Option[String])

class Application @Inject()(db: Database) extends Controller {

  val campaign = {
    get[Int]("campaign.id") ~
    get[Option[Int]]("campaign.campaign_mode_id") ~
    get[Option[String]]("campaign.name") map {
      case id ~ campaign_mode_id ~ name  => Campaign(id, campaign_mode_id, name)
    }
  }

  def index = Action {
    val data : List[Campaign] = db.withConnection { implicit connection =>
      SQL("SELECT id, name FROM campaign").as(campaign.*)
    }

    Ok(views.html.index(data))
  }
}
```

This code produces following error:

```
[RuntimeException: campaign.campaign_mode_id not found, available columns : campaign.id, id, campaign.name, name]
```

Comment: What do you fill in for `campaign_mode_id: Int` and  `name: String` when the columns aren't there? Maybe you should use `Option[Int]` and `Option[String]`.

Comment: @m-z I think `null`, but I'm not actually sure what is the best way to handle   it in Scala, may-be there is a batter approach ?

Comment: If you want to use `null` from the Java school of thought, you should instead use `Option` in Scala.

Comment: Thanks for advice. I updated the code, and now it doesn't work. How can I fix it ?

Comment: The Anorm documentation is indicating [how to deal with nullable/optional values](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaAnorm#Working-with-optional/nullable-values).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the column `campaign_mode_id` is nullable, parses to `Option[Int]` and is always present in the result set, use:

```
get[Option[Int]]("campaign.campaign_mode_id")
```

If the column `campaign_mode_id` is not nullable, may not appear in the result set, and parses to `Option[Int]`, use:

```
get[Int]("campaign.campaign_mode_id").?
```

In your case, it seems like you want:

```
val campaign = {
  get[Int]("campaign.id") ~
  get[Int]("campaign.campaign_mode_id").? ~
  get[String]("campaign.name").? map {
     case id ~ campaign_mode_id ~ name  => Campaign(id, campaign_mode_id, name)
  }
}
```

This assumes that `campaign.campaign_mode_id` and `compaign.name` are both non-nullable, but are optional in the result set.

Comment: Hey @MichaelZajac, doesn't `?` cover both cases: column may not appear in the result set _or_ it may be in the result set and may be null? The answer suggests it's only applicable when the column is not nullable.